# How do I get my voting system code to work with Parse?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have been trying to create a voting system so I can log the votes a certain image gets and display them in a cell.

I can't seem to get my voting to work properly I'm currently trying to use the += and -= operands because I couldn't figure out the increment count, but I keep getting an error message on post.count += or -= 1 of : `PFObject does not have a member named count` which I do in my parse backend:

[image: Parse]

Here is my code that i have so far:

```
import UIKit
import Parse


class HomePage: UITableViewController {

    let post = PFObject(className: "Post")
    var images = [UIImage]()
    var titles = [String]()
    var imageFile = [PFFile]()
    var count = [Int]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        println(PFUser.currentUser())

        var query = PFQuery(className:"Post")
        query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
        query.limit = 15
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {(objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil  {
                println("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) scores.")
                println(objects!)
                if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                for object in objects {

                        if let title = object["Title"] as? String {
                            self.titles.append(title)
                        }
                        if let imgFile = object["imageFile"] as? PFFile {
                            self.imageFile.append(imgFile)
                        }
                        if let voteCounter = object["count"] as? Int {
                        self.count.append(voteCounter)
                    }

                    self.tableView.reloadData()

                }
            } else {
                // Log details of the failure
                println(error)
            }
        }

    }
    }




                /* println("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) scores.")

                for object in objects! {

                    self.titles.append(object["Title"] as! String)

                    self.imageFile.append(object["imageFile"] as! PFFile)

                    self.tableView.reloadData()

                }*/



    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return titles.count

    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 500

    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var myCell:cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell") as! cell

        myCell.rank.text = "21"
        myCell.votes.text = "\(count)"
        myCell.postDescription.text = titles[indexPath.row]

        imageFile[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (data, error) -> Void in

            if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!) {

                myCell.postedImage.image = downloadedImage

            }
        }

        var swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "respondToSwipeGesture:")
        swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right
        myCell.postedImage.userInteractionEnabled = true;
        myCell.postedImage.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)

        var swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "respondToSwipeGesture:")
        swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left
        myCell.postedImage.userInteractionEnabled = true;
        myCell.postedImage.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)

        return myCell

    }


    func respondToSwipeGesture(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {

        if let swipeGesture = gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {
            switch swipeGesture.direction {
                case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right:
                post.count += 1
                println("Swiped right")
                case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left:
                post.count -= 1
                    println("Swiped Left")
                default:
                    break
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

How can I make the count work in this code? Why do I keep getting that error and how can I log the count for each specific image?

any type of voting system code would be appreciated i can change it up i just want to keep the swipe gesture as the way you upvote and downvote.

Comment: side note: xcode tag is for IDE issues. leave it alone

Answer (score 1):

Your table has a number of lines (at least four) that don't have any "`count`" parameters.  Delete them, or change your code to do this:

```
var potentialVoteCounter : Int? = object["count"]

if potentialVoteCounter == nil {        
   // create "count" in this Parse object
   let zero:NSNumber = 0
    object["count"] = zero
}

if let voteCounter = object["count"] as? Int {
    self.count.append(voteCounter)
}
```

or

```
if let voteCounter = object["count"] as? Int {
   // do nothing here...
} else {
   // create "count" in this object
   let zero:NSNumber = 0
   object["count"] = zero;
}

if let voteCounter = object["count"] as? Int {
   self.count.append(voteCounter)
}
```

making certain to save your updated Parse object at the end (so the table will reflect changes that you made)

Comment: sorry @Michael Dautermann im pretty new where should i add this code? in the viewDidLoad?

Comment: try the place where you have the current code and let me know what happens.

Comment: the potentiaVoteCounter isnt working with the error object (which i put as post which is my PFObject) cannot be converted to Int. the second one works but i still get the error at my switch statement with the post.count saying that post does not have a member named count

Comment: Yeah, your Parse column is expecting NSNumber objects and so we can't simply set `"count"` to an Int.  I've modified my code a little bit.

Comment: im still getting the error for my post.count at the switch statement that post does not have a member named count. I probably didnt create  the "count" correctly inside the else statement

Comment: I think the problem is more like you didn't set "`post`" to be the same (updated) Parse object you added the `"count"` column to in the other function.  If `post` is simply the blank PFObject you set at the top of your class, then it's an empty PFObject with nothing to go with it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78883/discussion-between-danielwolfgangtrebek-and-michael-dautermann).